# How to do VASP convergence tests, and how to get two plots of Encut and k-points wrt to total energy? I want to do convergence for Mg2Si

Tags: vasp, convergence-test

I am using VASP for the first time and do not know how to do convergence tests. How are convergence tests done in VASP and how do we get two plots of Encut and k-points with respect to total energy? I want to do these things for the $\ce{Mg2Si}$ material.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here, and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!! I've made some edits to you question though, please make note of them for next time.

Comment: This has already been answered on this network in multiple questions. For a start, this should help: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/k-points-and-encut-convergence-tests-before-or-after-relaxation

Comment: Thank you so much its a nice platform for research scholars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find @Andrew Rosen's nice answer from this post:[k-points and ENCUT convergence tests before or after relaxation?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/k-points-and-encut-convergence-tests-before-or-after-relaxation), as @Xixi76 suggested.

Besides, you can read this nice tutorial: https://dannyvanpoucke.be/vasp-tutor-convergence-testing-en/

It should be emphasized that the convergence test is one of the most important steps to obtain physical results.